# Gtk# and treeview: how to get "selected" item?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

i can't understand in GTK# how to get the selected item of a treeview. 
My code example:
Here, i load data in tvStock

```
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn marketCol = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn ();
            marketCol.Title = "Market";

            tvstock.AppendColumn(marketCol);

            Gtk.TreeIter iter = stockListStore.AppendValues ("Dax30");      

            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Adidas");
            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Commerzbank");

            iter = stockListStore.AppendValues ("Cac40");       
            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Bnp Paribas");
            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Veolia");

            iter = stockListStore.AppendValues ("FtseMib");     
            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Fiat");
            stockListStore.AppendValues(iter, "Unicredit");

            tvstock.Model = stockListStore;

            // Create the text cell that will display the artist name
            Gtk.CellRendererText marketNameCell = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
            // Add the cell to the column
            marketCol.PackStart (marketNameCell, true);     

            // Tell the Cell Renderers which items in the model to display
            marketCol.AddAttribute (marketNameCell, "text", 0);
```

On my *OnTvstockRowActivated* , how can i get the selected row ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the path to the row in args, you can gen an iter from it.

```
protected virtual void OnTvstockRowActivated (object o, Gtk.RowActivatedArgs args)
{
    var model = tvstock.Model;
    TreeIter iter;
    model.GetIter (out iter, args.Path);
    var value = model.GetValue (iter, 0);
    Console.WriteLine (value);
}
```